# How to sort a list of tibbles, by a value within tibble

Tags: r

I have created a list of tibbles thanks to the split() function in R. This list is simply called 'b'. When I call the variable, it looks like what you see in the attached picture.

Now, I want to rearrange each tibble within the list, such that it is sorted by 'n' in descending order. This way, I can view the 'top performers' for each month. The Job Family Group and Location Country can shift around; I do not need to group by either of them.

Can anyone advise how I can go about this? Tried with order/arrange/lapply, etc. but I keep getting errors.

Thank you.

[image]

Examples of attempts:

**Attempt to go entry by entry, and try an 'arrange', so that I can create a for loop**

```
 b[1]%>%arrange(.,desc(n))
Error in UseMethod("arrange") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange' applied to an object of class "list"
```

**Attempt to sort**

```
> sort(b[8])
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

**Attempt to arrange through dplyr**

```
> b[1]%>%arrange(.,desc(n))
Error in UseMethod("arrange") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(.x = b,
    .f = ~.x %>%
      arrange(-n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), \(x) x[order(x$hp),])
```